# How to retrieve particular product's order using Shopify API

Tags: api, shopify

I checked Shopify API(https://docs.shopify.com/api/order#index) but there is **no endpoint** I found by which we can filter particular product's order list.

Is there anyway to grab specific product's order in Shopify?

Answer (score 1):

Work it the other way around. Download all your orders, then iterate through those looking for the specific product of interest. An Order has many products, and a Product does belong to an Order, but there is no API call that will give you the orders that have any one Product.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all orders using the following endpoint :

GET /admin/orders.json

This will return a list of line items with product ids, which should contain the products you are looking for.

One thing to note here is that Shopify might throttle your requests if you keep querying their servers. Make sure you account for that in your code.